# Javascript- code getting executed before all elements are ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in my web. This page takes multiple image files as input and displays them before uploading them to server.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>File API - FileReader</h1>
    </header>

    <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label>

    <input id="files" type="file" multiple/>
    <div id='10' style=" width:100px; height:50px; background-color:#006633" onclick="submit_rr(event)">Click</div>
    <output id="result" />
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    function submit_rr(event){
        $('#files').click();
    }   

    $("#files").change(function(){
        show_selected(this);
    });


    function show_selected(input){

        for(i = 0;i< input.files.length; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var img = new Image;
                img.onload = function() {           
                    if(img.width>=img.height){
                        ratio=img.height/img.width;
                        height=ratio*100;
                        height_rem=(100-height)/2;
                        var crt=document.createElement('div');
                        crt.id="main_some";
                        crt.className="ind_req_sty";

                        var Friend="Friend";
                        crt.innerHTML="<img id="+i+" width='100px' height='"+height+"px' src='"+e.target.result+"'/>";
                        document.getElementById('10').appendChild(crt);           
                    }else{
                        ratio=img.width/img.height;
                        width=ratio*100;
                        var crt=document.createElement('div');
                        crt.id='main_req';
                        crt.className="ind_req_sty";

                        crt.innerHTML="<img id="+i+" height='100px' width='"+width+"' src='" + e.target.result +"'/>";
                        document.getElementById('10').appendChild(crt);               
                    }
                }
                img.src=reader.result;
            }    
        }

    }   
</script>
</html>
```

Problem is that, this script executes before all the elements are displayed. As a result only few images are displayed(say 4 out of 10 selected). I tried adding .ready() and .load() but that doesn't work. However if I add an alert('something') all images are displayed without any issue. is there a way I can delay execution so that all images are loaded. I have also tried setTimeout() without any luck. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you properly indent your code, you will set that `$("#files).change(/*..*/)` line is not inside the `submit_rr` function.

Wrap all your code with

```
$(function () {
    /* your code here */
});
```

Basically what it does is, creating event handler on dom ready event and after that we are executing our script.

Also, this is a commonly asked question. If you believe the problem you are having is not unique to your case, do your research, if you still cannot find the answer, go ahead and ask.
The link at http://whathaveyoutried.com tells about developers' feelings on answering a repeatedly asked question.

Comment: Hiii Thanks for your info. I did try this and it is still not working :(

Comment: You have too many issues with your code. You are leaking variables to global, you are trying to use non-declared elements, you are calling a function before defining it. Go ahead and fix those, do not expect us to fix all the errors in the code, put some effort in it, minimize angle of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `<script>` tag *before* the closing `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Hi After searching .....

I found this works ...

function eecute(event){

```
     var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
        var output = document.getElementById("result");

        for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
        {
            var file = files[i];

            //Only pics
            if(!file.type.match('image'))
              continue;

            var upload_pic = new FileReader();

            upload_pic.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                var pic_u = event.target;
                 var img = new Image;

                img.src=pic_u.result;
            if(img.width>=img.height){
                var div = document.createElement("cover");
                  div.innerHTML= "<div style='text-align: center; margin-top:8px; width:150px;margin-right:5px; height:150px;float:left'><img style='display:inline-block;' width='150' src='" + pic_u.result + "'/></div>"; 

                output.insertBefore(div,null); 

                }else{
                var div = document.createElement("cover");
                 div.innerHTML="<div style='text-align: center ;margin-top:8px;width:150px; margin-right:5px; height:150px;float:left'><img style='display:inline-block; margin:auto;' src='" + pic_u.result + "'height='150' /></div>";    
                     output.insertBefore(div,null); 
                    }


            });

             //Read the image
            upload_pic.readAsDataURL(file);
        }                               

   }
```